# Connect to Azure Cassandra Managed Instance from Janus Graph docker container

Tags: azure, cassandra, janusgraph

I have troubles connecting to the Cassandra cluster set up in Azure from the JanusGraph docker container. Here's how the compose file (modified [docker-compose-cql-es](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-docker/blob/master/docker-compose-cql-es.yml)) looks like:

```
version: "3"

services:
  janusgraph:
    image: docker.io/janusgraph/janusgraph:latest
    container_name: jce-janusgraph
    environment:
      JANUS_PROPS_TEMPLATE: cassandra-es
      janusgraph.storage.backend: cql
      janusgraph.storage.hostname: 10.2.0.6,10.2.0.9
      janusgraph.index.search.hostname: jce-elastic
      janusgraph.storage.username: cassandra
      janusgraph.storage.password: *****
      SSL_VERSION: TLSv1_2
      SSL_VALIDATE: 'false'
    ports:
      - "8182:8182"
    networks:
      - jce-network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "bin/gremlin.sh", "-e", "scripts/remote-connect.groovy"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.0
    container_name: jce-elastic
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "http.host=0.0.0.0"
      - "network.host=0.0.0.0"
      - "transport.host=127.0.0.1"
      - "cluster.name=docker-cluster"
      - "xpack.security.enabled=false"
      - "discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=1"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    networks:
      - jce-network

networks:
  jce-network:
volumes:
  janusgraph-default-data:
```

I'm able to connect to cluster via cqlsh, with a few hacks in bash:

```
export SSL_VERSION=TLSv1_2
export SSL_VALIDATE=false
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work at all in a docker container. I receive the following error constantly:

```
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /10.2.0.9:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/10.2.0.9:9042] Connection has been closed), /10.2.0.6:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/10.2.0.6:9042] Connection has been closed))
```

So, is there any way to trust the certificate from the docker container? I'm not controlling Cassandra instances, so no way to turn off SSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to extract the public key with OpenSSL and it helped.

```
openssl s_client -connect <ip-of-node> -showcerts
```

Copied 0-level certificate into text file including ---begin--  ---end--- lines and save with `.pem` extension. Then converted `.pem` certificate to `.crt` format:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in <cert>.pem -out <cert>.crt
```

Imported the certificate to JKS truststore with the following command:

```
keytool -import -alias <cert-alias> -file <cert>.crt -storetype JKS -keystore server.truststore
```

Createed properties file with the following content (check the java version):

```
storage.backend=cql
storage.hostname=<ip of cassanrda instances>
storage.username=cassandra
storage.password=<password>
storage.cql.ssl.enabled=true
storage.cql.ssl.truststore.location=/usr/lib/jvm/java-<java-version>-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts
storage.cql.ssl.truststore.password=changeit
cache.db-cache=true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait=20
cache.db-cache-time=180000
cache.db-cache-size=0.25
index.search.backend=lucene
index.search.directory=<folder for indices>
```

Then I with the gremlin shell I created the factory with graph end everything worked.

```
graph = JanusGraphFactory.open('<properties file>')
g = graph.traversal()
```

Everything can be packed to Dockerfile with those steps.